# unexpected T-Variable in php code and cant figure out why

Tags: php, syntax-error

I can't see where my error is coming from and I have checked for semicolons and can't see any missing. I'm fairly new to php and would appreciate the help greatly. The actual error reads:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   /home/sam/public_html/query.php on line 54

The following is line 54:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Users SET Datecreated='".$date."' WHERE Username='".$usernamec."'";
```

This is the full code:

```
<?php  session_start();

include 'connect.php';

echo "Hello World!";

echo '$_SESSION[page]';

$_SESSION['loggedon']=12345;
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'Users' WHERE 'Username'='".$username."'";
$result = @mysql_query( $sql );
while ($row= @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    if (($username=$row['Username'])&&($password=$row['Password']))
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedon']=$row['AccessLevel'];
        $_SESSION['userid']=$row['UserID'];}}


if ($_SESSION['loggedon']==12345)
    {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'RedundantUsers' WHERE 'Username'='".$username."'";
    $result = @mysql_query( $sql );
    while ($row= @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
            $_SESSION['loggedon']=$row['AccessLevel'];
            $_SESSION['userid']=$row['UserID'];


            $userid    =$row['UserID'];
            $forename  =$row['Forename'];
            $surname   =$row['Surname'];
            $email     =$row['Email'];
            $usernamec =$row['Username'];
            $access    =$row['AccessLevel'];


            $sql = "INSERT INTO 'Users' ('UserID', 'Forename', 'Surname', 'Email', 'Username', 'AccessLevel')
                    VALUES ('$userid', '$forename', '$surname', '$email', '$usernamec', '$access')";

                if (!@mysql_query($sql))    
                    {
                    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                        }
               $sql = "DELETE * FROM 'RedundantUsers' WHERE 'Username'='".$usernamec."'"; }}

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

        $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");    

            $sql = "UPDATE 'Users' SET 'Datecreated'='".$date."' WHERE 'Username'='".$usernamec."'";

                if (!@mysql_query($sql))    
                    {
                    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                        }


                    echo $_SESSION['loggedon']; 

header('Location: /'.$_SESSION['page']);

?>
```

In case it helps further here is connect.php:

```
<?php
$dbhost = '*****';
$dbuser = '*****'; 
$dbpass = '*****';  
$conn = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to local MySQL')
$dbname = '******';
@mysql_select_db($dbname);      
?>
```

Comment: You should use all array index names in quotes, e.g., `$row['UserID']` unless you've defined `UserID` as a constant. And include contents of your *connect.php* too

Comment: could be a naive question but are you sure the above code is from `query.php`?

Comment: ye and its not that stupid a question it was my first thought too was to double check i was editing the right code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 54 (where the error is occurring)

Change

`echo $_SESSION[loggedon];`

to

`echo $_SESSION['loggedon'];`

which means you forgot to include `'` in the session value. You should always include single quotes unless the value is a defined constant.

**UPDATE**

---

```
<?php  session_start();

include 'connect.php';

echo "Hello World!";

echo $_SESSION['page'];

    $_SESSION['loggedon']=12345;
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='".$username."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        if (($username=$row['Username'])&&($password=$row['Password']))
        {
            $_SESSION['loggedon']=$row['AccessLevel'];
            $_SESSION['userid']=$row['UserID'];}}


    if ($_SESSION['loggedon']==12345)
        {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM RedundantUsers WHERE Username='".$username."'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {   
                $_SESSION['loggedon']=$row['AccessLevel'];
                $_SESSION['userid']=$row['UserID'];


                $userid    =$row['UserID'];
                $forename  =$row['Forename'];
                $surname   =$row['Surname'];
                $email     =$row['Email'];
                $usernamec =$row['Username'];
                $access    =$row['AccessLevel'];




                $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (UserID, Forename, Surname, Email, Username, AccessLevel)
                        VALUES ('$userid', '$forename', '$surname', '$email', '$usernamec', '$access')";

                    if (!mysql_query($sql))    
                        {
                        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                            }
                   $sql = "DELETE * FROM RedundantUsers WHERE Username='".$usernamec."'"; }}

        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

            $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");  
            global $usernamec;          

                $sql = "UPDATE Users SET Datecreated='".$date."' WHERE Username='".$usernamec."'";

                    if (!@mysql_query($sql))    
                        {
                        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                            }


                        echo $_SESSION[loggedon];   

    header('Location: /'.$_SESSION[page]);

    ?>
```

Comment: that didn't fix it but thanks anyway. Also just checked that is line 60 where it says echo $_SESSION[loggedon];

Comment: I think this line shouldn't be raising a "Unexpected T_VARIABLE" error. The php interpreter will assume that `loggedon` is a defined constant.

Comment: do the same thing for all your `SESSION[]` values. and it will be fixed

Comment: but there is no session[] on that line

Comment: @user2280254 to every `SESSION` that has a value. Include `'` in between

Comment: have just done so anyway and it hasnt fixed the error

Comment: it says at the top of the question

Comment: That line seems to be fine, but your codding is not right. Why are you not putting single quotes inside your value?

Comment: check it again ive added single quotes but im not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: The problem is `$usernamec` is define within `if ($_SESSION['loggedon']==12345)
        {` range, but you are calling it for update, but update query does not have access to that variable.

Comment: @user2280254 copy and paste my new answer, and tell me the outcome

Comment: changed $usernamec to $_SESSION[userid] and Username to UserID on that line and still recieve that error

Comment: your new code worked thankyou very much i never would have spotted that

Answer (score 1):

There are a few obvious issues here:

1. You are using `mysql_*` methods, where you should use MySQLi instead.
2. You are not ensuring that your included strings in your SQL queries are sanitised, therefore opening yourself up for SQL injections.
3. Your keys for arrays should be strings, which means put them in single quotes.
4. Switching from `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return half of the amount of data, but still work the same - no need to increase the memory usage for no reason.
5. Use backticks (`) to denote your table and column names, this helps keep your SQL neat, but also avoids any potential conflicts with reserved words etc.

So ultimately things like:

```
$row[UserID];
```

Should be turned into:

```
$row['UserID'];
```

Same for where you use `$_SESSION`, `$_POST` or other arrays in your code.

Also, be sure to take a look at [this tutorial](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) on MySQLi, especially also the part on escaping strings!

**Edit**:

You are using declarations within your `if` statements, instead of comparisons:

```
if (($username=$row[Username])&&($password=$row[Password]))
```

Should be:

```
if (($username==$row[Username])&&($password==$row[Password]))
```

Double check all of your `if` statements.

Comment: ok this hasnt answerred my question but thanks for the general pointers that i dont have the time left to follow

Comment: Did correcting the issues as outlined with the array keys help? Tidying your code up will also help narrow down the potential issues.

Comment: just done that and i still have that error

Comment: No this hasnt gotten rid of that error

Comment: I have updated my answer with another issue/suggestion.

Comment: it is alright @MichaelWright. Just forget my comment :)

Comment: tried that no luck but thanks for all the ideas and suggestions